# Having Multiple SetStates() in a Gesture Detector?

Tags: dart, flutter, setstate, gesturedetector

I can't get the set state to change in multiple areas from an onTap VoidCallback?

I have two AnimationController in different stateful widgets. What I would like to implement is that if controller1.value == 0.0 then it'll make sure that when onTap that the controller2.value == 1.0 and visa versa for if controller1.value == 1.0.

StatefulWidget bottom layer (passes the widget.onTapOpen/closed to the top layer)

```
onTap: () {
  _toggleExpandingSheetPanelVisibility();
  setState(() {
    if (_controller1.value == 0.0){
      widget.onTapOpen();
    }
    else if (_controller1.value == 1.0){
      widget.onTapClosed();
    }
  });
 },
```

StatefulWidget top layer

```
onTapOpen: _ensureVisible,
onTapClosed: _ensureInvisible,

 void _ensureVisible() {
 setState(() {
   if (_controller2.value == 0.0) {
     _toggleVisibility();
   }
 });
}

void _ensureInvisible() {
 setState(() {
   if (_controller2.value == 1.0) {
     _toggleVisibility();
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the code in `onTap` in `setState(...)` if you don't change the state. You already have `setState(...)` in `_ensureVisible()` and `_ensureInvisible()` where you actually change the state. Actually you probably would need it only in `_toggleVisibility()` but that code is not in your question. Would be a good idea to add tat. Please add the class declaration part of your code to make it more clear what widget contains what code.

Comment: I got rid of the setState(..) like you mentioned and included a > 0.5 instead of == 1.0 and it worked...forgot the values of the animation controller where > 1! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when `if (_controller2.value >` or `< 0.5)` then it would toggle the visibility.